# edit instructions directly in visual mode

Tags: radare2, patching, reassembly

I know we can edit opcodes in radare2's visual mode using `i`.
But is there any way to edit instructions directly in visual mode?

In my case, the instruction is:

```
jae 0x8048450
```

And I want change it to:

```
jnbe 0x8048450
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *assembling* - the reverse of "disassembling".

You can do so with the command `wa` (presumably, "write assembly"). It can be found in the [Radare2 cheat sheet](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/doc/intro.md):

```
wa jnz 0x400d24
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, when i run `wa jnbe 0x8048450`, radare2 write `ja 0x10090882`. radare2 result: `Written 6 bytes (jnbe 0x8048450) = wx 0f874a840408`. why?

Comment: @ali: because [they are the same](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html), and – apparently – radare2 defaults to the `jnbe` notation.

Comment: But i think `jnbe 0x8048450` and `ja 0x10090882` are not same operations. I received `SIGSEGV` after this change!

Comment: That's a bit confusing. Are you talking about the difference between `ja` and `jnbe`? Because they **are** exactly **the same instruction** (look at that web page I linked to–their codes are the same!). But the address in your examples are *not* the same, so it should not be surprising you get a different result. It also has nothing to do with the segfault–you changed the code, and so you probably broke something.

Comment: I looked, thanks. Problem are addresses. `731c           jae 0x8048450` after `wa ja 0x8048450` --> `0f8718000000   ja 0x8048450` and it's not true. And `731c           jae 0x8048450`  after `i` + `771c` --> `771c           jae 0x8048450` and it's true. `wa ja 0x8048450` and `i` + `771c` should be same. am i right?

Answer (score 1):

In visual mode, you can use the `A` command, to launch the interactive assembler, type your opcodes, and see in real time the corresponding hex code.

You could have found this command by typing `?`, to get help, in visual mode.

Comment: thanks, it's so useful! What is your idea about [my commented issue](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14223/edit-instructions-directly-in-visual-mode/14229#comment21185_14225)?